# Android SDK - Integrate Qype and other pub/shop/landmarks information

Tags: java, android, maps

Is it possible to integrate Qype into my android application?

Also, are there any other free open source apis whch allows places such as pubs and shops to be displayed with information and reviews about the location on a google map view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qype has an api that you can use at http://api.qype.com/ - you can learn more about it at http://www.qype.com/developers/api

Comment: Thank you, and you can use that for Android, iPhone and other platforms ?

Comment: Yes. The api works over http. You need to have a key for your application, that you can get from the qype site mentioned above.

Comment: Fair enough - thanks for the help :) Do you know of any other APIs which can be integrated into Android projects which retrieve similar information?